# absolute positioned a tag overflowing it container

Tags: html, css, sass

please i have a problem making an absolute positioned tag stay inside its parent element, i tried making the height of the parent element same as the total height of the child element it worked but is their a better way i can solve it?I added a snippet of the result below

```css
.team__members {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.item__member {
  width: 24%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.item__member-info {
  position: relative;
}

.team__member-name {
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="team__members">
  <div class="team__member">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="team__member-info">
      <div class="team_member-name">
        <h3>Katherine Wong</h3>
        <p>Facial & breast surgery</p>
      </div>
      <a href="#">view full profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
&__member{
    width: 24%;

    img{
        width:100%;
    }
    &-info{
       position: relative;

        a{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        }
    }
    &-name{
        position: absolute;
        h3{

        }
        p{

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with compiled CSS and HTML, preferrably in a StackOverflow code snippet we can preview? This will allow us to better understand your problem, as it is difficult to grasp your issue with what you have currently provided.

Comment: I've added a snippet

Comment: Looks like you're not providing your elements with inset properties such as `top` or `bottom` so it'll use `auto` which will be based off of the containing element's box and position in the flow. Could you also kindly provide what your expected result is?

Comment: The expected result is for the anchor tag "view full profile" should be inside the border

Comment: Have you tried `bottom: 0;` on your `a` element inside `.team__member-info`?

Comment: You have a typo in team_member-name. I guess it should be team__member-name instead. Also, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i want .team__member-name and the a tag to stay inside the parent element(.team__member-info) as block elements but the a tag overflows the parent element, when i added a height to the parent element to be more than the total height of .team__member-name and a tag i got the result i wanted but is there a way i can achieve the result i want without giving the parent element a height?